# Why isn't this idea generation?

Tags: discussion

Although I enjoyed the question, and wrote an answer, I can't for the life of me see why [the question about magic-using kings](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/38655/how-to-explain-magic-using-kings) isn't a clear-cut case of idea-generation.

- "I can't think of a single, dominant reason...."
- "What would be so widespread...."

It seems clear that the question boils down to this:

- Given the following setup
- Please provide ideas to justify it

I see no way to evaluate results other than the OP's preferences. The conditions specified are not "too broad" in the strong sense, but they're wide enough that a great many equally valid answers are possible.

Am I missing something?

Comment: We've already had a few discussions about IG, and it was removed as a close reason. It was generally agreed that a good part of what we do on WB is a form of IG. I, personally, don't believe it's IG (but I wrote it, so I'm biased).

Comment: The idea-generation reason wasn't removed because idea-generation questions are ok; it was removed because such question should be closed as either primarily opinion-based or too broad.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I realize that, but (as I said), I don't believe the question is IG. It presents a desired end result and asks for a way to make it happen given specific criteria. That's a style of question we have a lot of.

Comment: @Frostfyre I should have been clearer.  I was only referring to your comment; I haven't reviewed the question in, err, question.  A lot of our questions involve some IG; the ones that should get closed are closable for other reasons.

Comment: The real question I'm asking here is if you thought it was clear idea generation, why did you answer it in the first place? Your actions act as a kind of role model for newer and less experienced users on Worldbuilding, so when an experienced user like yourself answers an off-topic question, newer users will think this is the norm. We don't want that type of behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Sufficiently constrained scenario based questions are **on topic** per the discussions that we have had in chat and on meta over the last year.

The trick is *sufficiently* constrained...

Answer (score 1):

It is idea generation in a technical sense, but it's a single specific problem rather than a large vague idea which appears to be more acceptable to the community. I'd say "opinion based" if I was forced to pin it down to a reason to close, but I still like it as a question.